# Silverlight DataGrid - Validating New Rows When Have Not Edited Individual Cell

Tags: silverlight, validation, datagrid, silverlight-3.0, data-annotations

I have a silverlight datagrid.

Validation works very well using DataAnnotations. However if I add a new row to the grid I don't get validation kicking in until I actuall try and edit cells.

Is there no way to force the grid to validate when a cell has not been clicked on?

Answer (score 0):

Use DataGridTemplateColumn with TextBox and perform manual validation of item after you add it. See my question it is very related: [Silverlight DataGrid validation show validation error for all objects|properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947495/silverlight-datagrid-validation-show-validation-error-for-all-objectsproperties)